# For each row in a dataframe, loop through another dataframe

Tags: r, apply

I need to loop through a dataframe, read the value of three columns (2 timestamps and 1 label). Then, for this row of three values, I need to compare with each row of a second dataframe to see whether A) the label matches, and B) the timestamp that is in the second dataframe is between the two timestamps of the current row. If the row does indeed match these two criteria, it should be saved to a dataframe / vector for further processing.

I have tried many versions of the x_apply function, in combination with a for loop (for the 'second' iteration). Below is a very simplified version of my problem, where I create two small dataframes and try to establish the required looping. The value should be saved to 'x' - and while this value is shown when I print(x) in the loop, 'x' is claimed to be NULL after the apply function is completed. It appears to be reset every time the function is called as well. Taking my requirements into account, do you have ideas for a different / better approach? I am not required to use apply per se. Thank you very much in advance!

```
label <- c("p1", "p1", "p2")
value_1 <- c(8,4,2)
value_2 <- c(10,6,9)
df1 <- data.frame(label, value_1, value_2)

label <- c("p1", "p2", "p2")
value_3 <- c(8,8,8)
df2 <- data.frame(label, value_3)

x = NULL

small_function <- function(value_1, value_2, label) {
  for(i in 1:nrow(df2[df2$label == label,])) {
    print(i)
    x <- append(x, i)
    print(x)
  }
}

apply(df1, 1, function(x,y,z) small_function(df1$value_1, df1$value_2, df1$label))
x
```

Update: An example with time dates, resulting in the error "Expecting a single value" for me.

```
label <- c("p1", "p1", "p2")
value_1 <- c(as.POSIXct(1482645600, origin="1970-01-01"),as.POSIXct(1482745600, origin="1970-01-01"),as.POSIXct(1482845600, origin="1970-01-01"))
value_2 <- c(as.POSIXct(1582645600, origin="1970-01-01"),as.POSIXct(1582745600, origin="1970-01-01"),as.POSIXct(1582845600, origin="1970-01-01"))
df1 <- data.frame(label, value_1, value_2)
label <- c("p1", "p2", "p2")
value_3 <- c(as.POSIXct(1582645100, origin="1970-01-01"),as.POSIXct(1582745200, origin="1970-01-01"),as.POSIXct(1582845300, origin="1970-01-01"))
df2 <- data.frame(label, value_3)

df_merge = merge(df1, df2, c("label"), suffixes = c(".df1",".df2"))
setDT(df_merge)
str(df_merge)
a <- df_merge[between(value_3, value_1, value_2), ]
```

Comment: merge first and then apply your range conditions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)    
setkey(df1, label)
setkey(df2, label)
df1[df2]  # here i merge both the data.table

df3[between(value_3, value_1, value_2), ]  # apply the condition
#   label value_1 value_2 value_3
#1:    p1       8      10       8
#2:    p2       2       9       8
#3:    p2       2       9       8
```

---

with some Dates in data:

```
# ensure the dates are in proper formats( i had simulated some sample data with dates. just sharing the last 2 steps output)
df3$value_1 = as.Date(df3$value_1, format= "%d/%m/%Y")
df3$value_2 = as.Date(df3$value_2, format= "%d/%m/%Y")
df3$value_3 = as.Date(df3$value_3, format= "%d/%m/%Y")
# df3
#   label    value_1    value_2    value_3
#1:    p1 2016-03-10 2016-03-20 2016-03-15
#2:    p1 2016-06-17 2016-06-19 2016-03-15
#3:    p2 2016-09-10 2016-09-20 2016-06-21
#4:    p2 2016-09-10 2016-09-20 2016-09-12

df3[between(value_3, value_1, value_2), ]
#   label    value_1    value_2    value_3
#1:    p1 2016-03-10 2016-03-20 2016-03-15
#2:    p2 2016-09-10 2016-09-20 2016-09-12
```

Comment: This is great!
When I am using the between call on POSIXct values I do however get the error: "Error: expecting a single value". Any idea how I could resolve this?

Comment: Mind sharing a sample data with dates? I will look into it..it will be an easy fix. Merry Christmas...going to church now

Comment: thank you and a wonderful Christmas to you as well :) I have edited my first question with an update that contains some more sample data. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @WalterB i checked your updated data and it worked for me! no errors at all!

Comment: That's so strange! I just reran the code and I still get that error.. no clue what is going wrong. Any ideas on what I can try?

Comment: @WalterB could you share the version of `data.table` ? `InfoSession()`

Comment: data.table_1.9.6 and R version 3.3.1.

Comment: @WalterB even i have the sme version.. I'm absolutely clueless about this error !! your code works perfectly fine on mine. did you get the error when you ran on the entire dataset? or on this sample data itself? and you get this error on the last line code right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very short solution in base R, if this is what you are looking for:

```
dfr <- merge(df1, df2, by="label", all=FALSE)
subset(dfr, value_3 > value_1 & value_3 < value_2)
```